# Get row with highest value from one column after chunking with plyr - R

Tags: r, plyr

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
r1 1  2  2  4  5  9
r2 1  2  2  4  5  10
r3 1  2  2  4  5  7
r4 1  2  2  4  5  12
r5 2  2  2  4  5  9
r6 2  2  2  4  5  10
```

I would like to get the row with the highest value in v6 that has the value 1 in v1.
I know how to get all rows where v1 = 1 and select the first row of that, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18694724/1866639) to a previous question:

```
ddply( df , .variables = "v1" , .fun = function(x) x[1,] )
```

How can I change the function so that I get the row with the highest value in v6?

Comment: you should provide the code to produce your dataframe

Comment: Not sure about `ddply` but in `base` you can use: `intersect(which(df$v1==1), which.max(df$v6))` to find that row.

Comment: You should clarify whether you want the highest value of 'v6' or the row with the highest value of 'v6'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the previous results, I'd use `[` to subset on your first condition using `logical` comparators and then do a second subset on your second condition because as @sgibb points out in the comments, the `max` value of `v6` might not be in a row where `v1 == 1`.

```
#  Subset to those rows where v1 == 1
tmp <- df[ df$v1 == 1 , ]

#  Then select those rows where the max value of v6 appears
tmp[ tmp$v6 == max( tmp$v6 ) , ]
```

If you want the first occurence, use `which.max()`

Comment: +1 you can also consider adding the option of which.max in case they are just interested in the first match.

Comment: This won't work if the highest value is in a row with `df$v1 != 1`.

Comment: No, it's not of the entire dataframe, but of the chunks that I got with ddply. So I want the highest value of v6 for the chunk with v1 = 1, does that make sense?

Comment: @LukasKawerau yes. Working on it.

Comment: FYI, to avoid creating the `tmp` object, you can use compound queries with `data.frame`s too: `df[df$v1 == 1, ][which.max(df$v6), ]`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto that's nice syntax, but I'd be seriously surprised if at least the same number of copies of the data weren't made anyway. Using the intermediate step, I think just make the code just that little bit less obtuse (but I do prefer your compound query syntax).

Comment: @SimonO101, what about `data.table` then? I wonder if copying takes place with a similar approach.

Comment: @AnandaMahtowell yeah I'd expect that to work without making copies, as per the raison d'etre of `data.table`. I kinda want to build R with memory profiling now to test copy numbers. Maybe I'll do that tonight.

Answer (score 0):

we could also use the `subset` operator like

```
x_sub= subset(x, state == "C" & chainlength == 5 & segment == "C2C_REG")
```

where x is the data frame and the other parameter is a logical expression